# Copy paste to different tabs

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project to find a project on active projects tabs along with active tasks tab, to achieve project and tasks tabs. The .Rows is some code i found somewhere else on stackoverflow. It doesn’t seem to work though.

```
Sub Try2()
 
Dim ArchiveRangeProjects As Range 'range to look for project number in active projects worksheet
Dim ArchiveRangeTasks As Range 'range to look for project number in active tasks worksheet
Dim ArchiveRangeProjectsDelete As Range
Dim ArchiveRangeTasksDelete As Range
Dim ActiveProjectsWS As Worksheet
Dim ArchiveProjectsWS As Worksheet
Dim ActiveTasksWS As Worksheet
Dim ArchiveTasksWS As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim startrow As Long
Dim counter As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim ActPjtbl As ListObject
Dim ArcPjtbl As ListObject
Dim ActTktbl As ListObject
Dim ArcTktbl As ListObject
 
 
    Set ActiveProjectsWS = Sheets("Active Projects")
    Set ArchiveProjectsWS = Sheets("Archive Projects (2022)")
    Set ActiveTasksWS = Sheets("Tasks")
    Set ArchiveTasksWS = Sheets("Archive Tasks (2022)")
   
    Call wsResponseFunction
 
    Set ArchiveRangeProjects = Worksheets("Active Projects").Range("A:D").Find(ProjNum)
    Set ArchiveRangeTasks = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("A:D").Find(ProjNum)
    Set ArchiveRangeProjectsDelete = Worksheets("Active Projects").Range("A:D").Find(ProjNum)
    Set ArchiveRangeTasksDelete = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("A:D").Find(ProjNum)
 
    Set ActPjtbl = ActiveProjectsWS.ListObjects("Active_Projects")
    Set ArcPjtbl = ArchiveProjectsWS.ListObjects("Archive_Projects")
    Set ActTktbl = ActiveTasksWS.ListObjects("Tasks")
    Set ArcTktbl = ArchiveTasksWS.ListObjects("Archive_Tasks")
 
 
             
    'move selected projects from the active tab to the archive project tab
    If Not ArchiveRangeProjects Is Nothing Then
        lr = ArchiveProjectsWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
         .Rows(ArchiveRangeProjects.Row).EntireRow.Copy 'copy row
         ArchiveProjectsWS.Rows(lr).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'        ArchiveRangeProjects.Copy ArchiveProjectsWS.Cells(lr, "A")
         .Rows(ArchiveRangeProjects.Row).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp 'delete row
        MsgBox "projects done"
        If Not ArchiveTasksRange Is Nothing Then
        lastrow = ArchiveTasksWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
         .Rows(ArchiveRangeTasks.Row).EntireRow.Copy 'copy row
         ArchiveTasksWS.Rows(lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste row
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'        ArchiveRangeProjects.Copy ArchiveProjectsWS.Cells(lr, "A")
         .Rows(ArchiveRangeTasks.Row).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp 'delete row
        MsgBox "tasks done"
 
    Else
        MsgBox "There are no projects associated with the " & ProjNum & " project number."
        Exit Sub
    End If
 
 
 
End Sub
 
 
Function wsResponseFunction()
'This function creates a pop up box to enter the project number that needs to be archived
'It saves the entered project number as a variable to be used later
 
    wsresponse = InputBox("Enter the project number that you want to archive.")
 
    ProjNum = wsresponse
 
End Function
```

Comment: *It doesn’t seem to work though* Please, be more specific. Besides, using the notation `.Object` usually means there is an `With...End With` statement somewhere else.

Comment: It says compile error: Invalidr or unqualified reference while .Rows  is highlighted.

Comment: `.Rows(...` - this line needs to sit inside a `With... End With` block to work.

Comment: so what should i add? With … what?

Comment: You should add a `With... End With` block referenced to the right object (probably a Worksheet object in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the property without referencing to the object.
In this case, it'd be your ArchiveRangedProjects, however (imo) it's more logical to reference to the worksheet, rather than the range since you're also needing lastrow:

```
Sub Try2()
 
    Dim ArchiveRangeProjects As Range 'range to look for project number in active projects worksheet
    Dim ArchiveRangeTasks As Range 'range to look for project number in active tasks worksheet
    Dim ArchiveRangeProjectsDelete As Range
    Dim ArchiveRangeTasksDelete As Range
    Dim ActiveProjectsWS As Worksheet
    Dim ArchiveProjectsWS As Worksheet
    Dim ActiveTasksWS As Worksheet
    Dim ArchiveTasksWS As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim startrow As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim ProjNum As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ActPjtbl As ListObject
    Dim ArcPjtbl As ListObject
    Dim ActTktbl As ListObject
    Dim ArcTktbl As ListObject
 
 
    
    Set ActiveProjectsWS = Sheets("Active Projects")
    Set ArchiveProjectsWS = Sheets("Archive Projects (2022)")
    Set ActiveTasksWS = Sheets("Tasks")
    Set ArchiveTasksWS = Sheets("Archive Tasks (2022)")
   
    ProjNum = wsResponseFunction
 
    Set ArchiveRangeProjects = ActiveProjectsWS.Range("A:D").Find(ProjNum)
    Set ArchiveRangeTasks = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("A:D").Find(ProjNum)
    Set ArchiveRangeProjectsDelete = Worksheets("Active Projects").Range("A:D").Find(ProjNum)
    Set ArchiveRangeTasksDelete = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("A:D").Find(ProjNum)
 
    Set ActPjtbl = ActiveProjectsWS.ListObjects("Active_Projects")
    Set ArcPjtbl = ArchiveProjectsWS.ListObjects("Archive_Projects")
    Set ActTktbl = ActiveTasksWS.ListObjects("Tasks")
    Set ArcTktbl = ArchiveTasksWS.ListObjects("Archive_Tasks")
 
 
     
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'move selected projects from the active tab to the archive project tab
    If Not ArchiveRangeProjects Is Nothing Then
        With ArchiveProjectsWS
            lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ArchiveRangeProjects.Rows.EntireRow.Copy 'copy row
            .Range("A" & lr).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste row
        End With
'        ArchiveRangeProjects.Copy ArchiveProjectsWS.Cells(lr, "A")
            ArchiveRangeProjects.Rows.EntireRow.Delete 'delete row
        MsgBox "projects done"
        If Not ArchiveTasksRange Is Nothing Then
        With ArchiveTasksWS
            lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ArchiveRangeTasks.Rows.EntireRow.Copy 'copy row
            .Range("A" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste row
        End With
'        ArchiveRangeProjects.Copy ArchiveProjectsWS.Cells(lr, "A")
         ArchiveRangeTasks.Rows.EntireRow.Delete 'delete row
        MsgBox "tasks done"
 
    Else
        MsgBox "There are no projects associated with the " & ProjNum & " project number."
        Exit Sub
    End If
 
 
 
End Sub
Function wsResponseFunction()
'This function creates a pop up box to enter the project number that needs to be archived
'It saves the entered project number as a variable to be used later
 
    wsResponseFunction = InputBox("Enter the project number that you want to archive.")
    'not quite what we use a function for but you give the response with the name of the function
End Function
```

Try this out, adjusted some of your code like with how you'll want to store the function value (for things like this you could just put the value directly without needing the function but this way you can see how it's normally used)

Hope this helps, if not feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rework of your code, removing some unnecessary lines.

One issue I noticed is that your Range.Find lines are likely to cause issues as you don't specify all the minimum parameters to enable Excel to search consistently.

I've also added some better commentary lines to help you learn what's happening.

I elected to not use `With.. End With` blocks but instead just fully qualify the ranges. This helps keep things simple when learning how to use objects.

```
Sub try3()
  
   Dim ArchiveRangeProjects As Range 'range to look for project number in active projects worksheet
   Dim ArchiveRangeTasks As Range 'range to look for project number in active tasks worksheet
   Dim ActiveProjectsWS As Worksheet
   Dim ArchiveProjectsWS As Worksheet
   Dim ActiveTasksWS As Worksheet
   Dim ArchiveTasksWS As Worksheet
   
   Dim lr As Long
   Dim lastrow As Long
  
   Set ActiveProjectsWS = Sheets("Active Projects")
   Set ArchiveProjectsWS = Sheets("Archive Projects (2022)")
   Set ActiveTasksWS = Sheets("Tasks")
   Set ArchiveTasksWS = Sheets("Archive Tasks (2022)")
  
   Call wsResponseFunction

   Set ArchiveRangeProjects = Worksheets("Active Projects").Range("A:D").Find(what:=ProjNum, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
   Set ArchiveRangeTasks = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("A:D").Find(what:=ProjNum, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)

   'move selected projects from the active tab to the archive project tab

   'if ProjNum was found..
   If Not ArchiveRangeProjects Is Nothing Then
   
       'find lastrow (lr) of ArchiveProjectsWS examining column A
       lr = ArchiveProjectsWS.Cells(ArchiveProjectsWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
       
       'copy row where ProjNum was found
        ArchiveRangeProjects.EntireRow.Copy
        
       'paste (special - values) row
        ArchiveProjectsWS.Rows(lr).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   
       'copy ProjNum to cell A - commented out? Is this required?
       'ArchiveRangeProjects.Copy ArchiveProjectsWS.Cells(lr, "A")
       
       'delete row where ProjNum was found
       ArchiveRangeProjects.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
       
       'alert user
       MsgBox "projects done"
   
   Else
       'alert ProjNum not found in Projects
       MsgBox "There are no projects associated with the " & ProjNum & " project number."
       Exit Sub 'comment this line out if you want to try to move task even if ProjNum not found in projects
   End If
      
   'move selected tasks from the active tab to the archive task tab
      
   'if ProjNum was found..
   If Not ArchiveRangeTasks Is Nothing Then
   
       'find lastrow (lr) of ArchiveTasksWS examining column A
       lastrow = ArchiveTasksWS.Cells(ArchiveTasksWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
       
       'copy row where ProjNum was found
        ArchiveRangeTasks.EntireRow.Copy
        
       'paste (special - values) row
        ArchiveTasksWS.Rows(lr).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   
       'copy ProjNum to cell A - commented out? Is this required?
       'ArchiveRangeTasks.Copy ArchiveTasksWS.Cells(lr, "A")
       
       'delete row where ProjNum was found
       ArchiveRangeTasks.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
       
       'alert user
       MsgBox "tasks done"
   
   Else
       'alert ProjNum not found in Tasks
       MsgBox "There are no tasks associated with the " & ProjNum & " project number."
   End If

End Sub
```